# Make or simulate a join in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, entity-relationship

I would like to simulate a join query in mongodb using mongoose. There is no nested data, just two Schemas, where the OrderSchema:_id, is referencing DetailSchema: orderId

It's a bad solution to get all the orders and then query each of their details one by one. I have tried using populate in mongoose, but that only worked if i changed the scheme, and that is **not** a possibility. I simply cannot think of a clean way to do it!

```
var OrderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    customerId: String,
    employeeId: Number,
    orderDate: String,
    requiredDate: String,
    shippedDate: String,
    shipVia: String,
    freight: Number,
    shipName: 
});
exports.OrderModel = mongoose.model('orders', OrderSchema);

var DetailsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    orderId: Number,
    productId: 
    quantity: Number,
    discount: Number
});
```

Comment: I would have changed the Schema if i could, but the database have been created and populated with data. Sp i need to find a way to make the join without changing the Schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `DetailSchema` definition to define `orderId` as a reference to `Order`:

```
var DetailsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    orderId: {type: Number, ref: 'Order'},
    productId: Number,
    quantity: Number,
    discount: Number
});
```

This doesn't require any change to the actual data in your existing doc, the `ref` is just metadata that Mongoose uses to know which model's `_id` the field contains a reference to.

With that in place, you can use `populate` to pull in the order details as:

```
Details.find().populate('orderId').exec(function(err, details) { ... });
```

Comment: but that brings me to another question. If ref points to the _id, can i make it so i can join on like a name or something else. And is the Schema just at model for how i want my data to be displayed. And thank for you answer :) it worked like a charm

Comment: Glad it helped! It's best to post follow-ups as new questions.